# Jquery Accordion menu issue - user can have more than one answer open

Tags: jquery

I've created a jquery slide menu but currently the menu allows users to have more than one answer open at any time - I would ideally like only one open at any one time. Has anyone any idea how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/XMLgz/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.info').hide();

$(".faqSubhead").click(function() {
    var $body = $(this).next(".info")
    $('.info').slideUp('fast');
    if ($body.is(":hidden")) {
        $body.slideDown('fast');
    }
});
```

Just slideUp all .info elements within function and slideDown selected element.

See http://jsfiddle.net/XMLgz/8/

Comment: The advantage to the other solution from @Simon is that you also can hide all answers.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Compacted it a bit..

```
$(".faqSubhead").click(function() {
    $('.info').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next(".info").slideDown('fast');
});
```

​Perhaps?